# APNS certificate expiry issue for Hybrid application

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

Got the APNS certificate for my Hybrid app (using Mobilefirst) generated yesterday. The expiry date for the certificate is 12 July 2016. But when I try to build the app using Mobile first application am getting an error saying "The APNS certificate expired on Oct 31, 2014 18:49." The certificate name is apns-certificate-production.p12

I tried recreating the environment, clearing the cache etc.. but of no help

Any help regarding solving this issue is appreciable.

[image]

Comment: How did you generate the .p12 certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have generated my p.12 the following way and I do not encounter this error:

1. After creating the certificate in the Apple Developer site, I downloaded the .cer file
2. "Installed" the .cer file by double-clicking it, and have it added to my Keychain.
3. Expended the certificate in Keychain and selected both it and the private key in it
4. Exported and provided a password for it
5. Copied the .p12 file into myProject\apps\myApp folder
6. In application-descriptor.xml added the `pushSender` child element for the iPhone element with the certificate password as its value
7. Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server

The build has passed.

Comment: Hi @ldan, Tested the app in Iphone and the push notification is working fine. Looks like the warning is false one. Still the warning is there while building the app but the push notification works